# Is there way to inherit templates with mixins in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Someone knows how inherit a `mixin` with its template? or how to inject dinamically elements or components from a `mixin`?

**EDIT:**
I don't want to modify greeting component, I have two Mixins: 404Mixin that adds a method raise404() and show a 100% layer and LoaderMixin that have loading() method that shows a spinner in the corner. I can inherit their methods, but I have to duplicate the html in every component that I want to use it.

Thanks

```js
mixin = {
  template: '<p>{{ foo }}</p>',
  data() {
    return {
      foo: 'Hello',
    };
  },
}

// This should  be <div><p>Hello</p><p>World!</p></div>
Vue.component('greeting', {
  mixins: [mixin],
  template: '<div><p>World!</p></div>'
});

var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <greeting></greeting>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please explain what you're actually trying to accomplish? Your example code seems to work fine.

Comment: I want to inherit the mixin template, I want to print `<div><p>Hello</p><p>World!</p></div>`, I have a more complex code, but I've created the example code to represent the problem.

Comment: Well it certainly seems that at least at first glance you're missing a prerequisite slot.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After years, I can imagine a elegant solution, and maybe it could be more elegant using classes, typescript or an annotation that create the component super in the mixin, but for now, the problem is partial solved.

```js
GreetingMixin = {
  data() {
    return {
      greeting: 'Hello',
    };
  },
  provide() { return {child: this}},
  components: {
    super: {
      inject: ['child'],
      template: '<div class="blue">{{ child.greeting }} <strong><slot /></strong></div>',
    }
  },
}


// This should be <div class="blue">Hello <strong>World!</strong></div>
Vue.component('welcomeWorld', {
  mixins: [GreetingMixin],
  template: '<super>World!</super>',
});

// This should be <div class="blue">Hi <strong><i>ali</i></strong></div>
Vue.component('welcomeName', {
  mixins: [GreetingMixin],
  props: ["name"],
  created() { this.greeting = "Hi" },
  template: '<super><i>{{ name }}</i></super>',
});

// This should be <h1><div class="blue">Hello <strong>World</strong></div></h1>
Vue.component('welcomeH1', {
  mixins: [GreetingMixin],
  props: ["name"],
  template: '<h1><super>{{ name }}</super></h1>',
});


var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

```css
.blue {
color: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <welcome-world></welcome-world>
  <welcome-name name="Ali"></welcome-name>
  <welcome-h1 name="Ali"></welcome-h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks useful, but I don't understand how and why it works. Could you give some references or explanations?  .... Is it actually creating a local component that is used by "greeting"?  Will members from "greeting" be available when the template of "super" is rendered? ... Ok, did an experiment... they will, I'll edit your answer with an extended example.

Comment: Sorry, your edition was incorrect, it worked for your tests, but you shouldn't  reference child properties from the parent, what you can, is reference parent properties from the child, see my edit with more child examples.

Comment: This is the reference to Ali's solution: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Dependency-Injection

Answer (score 6):

You can't "inherit" mixin templates like in your example, if it were possible there would have to be a standardized way of merging the templates.

Since it seems all you really want to do is inherit the template, why not use component composition with slots?

```js
Vue.component('not-found', {
  template: '#not-found',
  methods: {
    doSomethingSpecial() {
      alert('Hi there');
    },
  },
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      notFoundVisible: false,
    };
  },
});
```

```css
.not-found {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/vue/1.0.16/vue.js"></script>

<template id="not-found">
  <div class="not-found">
    <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>

<div id="app">
  <not-found v-show="notFoundVisible" @click="notFoundVisible = false" v-ref:not-found>The resource was not found</not-found>
  <button @click="notFoundVisible = true">Click Me</button>
  <button @click="$refs.notFound.doSomethingSpecial()">Do Something Special</button>
</div>
```

Is there any particular reason why you need to mixin these components instead of composing them together?

Comment: Yes, I had something like that, but I use loading methods before have $refs, and to it works I have to use props and custom methods then it gets too messy then I decided use mixins and I was wondering me if it could be more transparent.

Comment: I dont really see how adding a component with `alert()` helps with avoiding html duplication/DRY with page aspects, may it be slotted or slotless.