# Modifying the VueJS merge strategy to prioritize templates from a mixin

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have a simple Vue component and a mixin that I am bringing into that component. Both the component and the mixin have a template defined. When the mixin is merged into the component, the template defined at the component level is what is rendered to the document.

Is there any way to prioritize the template from the mixin over the one defined in the component? I would want this to be the setting throughout my application.

Simple code example of what I'm executing here:

HTML

```
<div id="component-test">
  <basic-component></basic-component>
</div>

<script type="text/x-template" id="hello">
  <div>
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
  </div>
</script>

<script type="text/x-template" id="welcome">
  <div>
    <h2>{{ message }}</h2>
    <hr />
    <p>{{ subMessage }}</h2>
  </div>
</script>
```

JS

```
const Modify = {
  data() {
    return {
      subMessage: "Welcome to Vue."
    }
  },
  template: '#welcome'
}

const Basic = {
  data() {
    return {
      message: "Hello World!"
    }
  },
  template: '#hello',
  mixins: [Modify]
}

new Vue({ 
  el: '#component-test',
  components: {
    'basic-component': Basic
  }
})
```

Comment: Pretty sure this isn't possible, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45001604/is-there-way-to-inherit-templates-with-mixins-in-vuejs :(

Comment: I did see this thread but thought my situation a little different. I don't need to merge the templates or inherit anything into the component. What I'm wondering is if both the component and mixin have a template defined, can we use the mixin template and not the component template?