# How to make a reusable template for a VueJS Mixin

Tags: vuejs2

I have (many pairs of) two components one that lists items and another that shows/edits details for a single item. Both have a context menu with relevant actions/information for selected items.
These actions/information are the same for both components.
Seems like what a Mixin is intended for.
Works great until an action needs to have information in the components template.

list.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <List :items="itemss" :actions="actionsFromActionsMixin">
    </List>

    <b-modal lazy id="modalTriggeredByAction1"  >
    </b-modal>
    <b-modal lazy id="modalTriggeredByAction2"  >
    </b-modal>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import List from '../crud_base/List';
  import { actionsMixin } from './actionsMixin.js'

  ...

</script>
```

item.vue

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Form :item="item" :actions="actionsFromActionsMixin">
    </Form>

    <b-modal lazy id="modalTriggeredByAction1"  >
    </b-modal>
    <b-modal lazy id="modalTriggeredByAction2"  >
    </b-modal>

  </div>
</template>
<script>
  import Form from '../crud_base/Form';
  import { actionsMixin } from './actionsMixin.js'

  ...

</script>
```

I really want to DRY the duplicated template parts, but I can not find how to do it other than making a component, and that is too "heavy" for my use-case.
I think this is a duplicate of [Is there way to inherit templates with mixins in VueJS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45001604) that did not get any good answer 2 years ago.

Comment: yes, you should use a HOC component and slots

Comment: @SimonThiel I found a bunch of references to Higher Order Components, but could not see how they would solve my problem. One of the main reasons I do not think I can use a normal component is that I use local variables in the Templates and the Mixin contains data used inside the components defined. This seems like it ought to be simple, something like put a tag "MixinTemplateHere" somewhere in my template and go on.

Comment: The referred question have got a useful answer :-)  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58619939/671282